# jshint option for flagging error with unused variable

Tags: javascript, syntax, jshint

​Jshint does not throw error in this case

```
var x;
x = 'aaa'; // The variable is never read
```

Is there a an option for this case?​​

Answer (score 0):

just add the following to the top of any files you'd like to apply this check too:

`/*jshint unused:true */`

Answer (score 0):

This code wont trigger the warning as you are using the declared variable writing a value to it. I don't know if there is an actual option to warning you in this specific case. Best is too look there [jshint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/).

unused option will trigger a warning only if you would have something like:
`var x = 'aaa';` and then not called anymore.

You can check as well maybe [jscs](http://jscs.info/rules) handle it I don't know